# SQL: tell whether columns are unique with respect to each other

Tags: sql

Suppose I've got a table:

```
Role
----
person_id company_id financial_year
```

How can I tell the following:

1. Whether each person_id occurs at most once per company_id per financial_year in this table
2. If 1. is false, which person_id's and company_id's and financial_year's co-occur more than once

Edit 1: Edited to add financial_year col

Edit 2: the RDBMS platform here happens to be MySQL, though I don't expect that this would require much vendor-specific SQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first, it's generally a good idea to just have a grouping which you can then filter on if you want:

```
select
  r.company_id, r.person_id, r.financial_year, count(r.person_id) 
from
  Role as r 
group by
  r.company_id, r.person_id, r.financial_year
```

For the second, you can just modify the above like so:

```
select
  r.company_id, r.person_id, r.financial_year, count(r.person_id) 
from
  Role as r 
group by
  r.company_id, r.person_id, r.financial_year
having
  count(r.person_id) > 1
```

Comment: The having clause should come after the Group by.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need:

```
select left.person_id, left.company_id, left.financial_year, count(*)
from role left
inner join role right
    on left.person_id = right.person_id 
        and left.company_id = right.company_id
        and left.financial_year = right.financial_year
group by left.person_id, left.company_id, left.financial_year
```

Note that this is T-SQL (MS), but the only thing I know of that might change is the table alias syntax, as the rest is ANSI SQL. This will return one row per repeated person/company/year combination, with a count of the number of times that combination is repeated (though the count wasn't mentioned in the question, I know it can sometimes be useful).

Comment: As written, it doesn't sort out financial years.  It will also return each entry in role because that row can be joined with itself.

Comment: I see the question was edited to add financial year - maybe you answered before that...

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it for #1:

```
select count(*), count(distinct person_id, company_id, financial_year)
    from role
```

(Edit: If the two count()'s are different, then the table contains multiple rows per unique combination of the three columns, what I was asking in question #1. Take the difference of them to get the number of such rows.)

and casperOne's answer will do it for #2

Comment: It lists everyone; you need a clause to limit the output to duplicates.  That might be the HAVING clause.

Comment: You can't put a list of columns into the COUNT() function.

Comment: Bill K, you can indeed put multiple cols in a count(distinct ...). This query works.

Comment: Jon L, not sure what you mean exactly. Question 1 was asking whether the table contained any such dupe rows, question 2 was what those rows were if they did exist.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in general, to detect duplicates,

```
Select [ColumnList you want to be unique]
From Table
Group By [SameColumn List]
Having Count(*) > 1
```

In your specific case

```
Select person_id, company_id, financial_year
From Table
Group By person_id, company_id, financial_year
Having Count(*) > 1
```

or, for your sub-question (1) about Whether each person_id occurs at most once per company_id per financial_year in this table

```
Select company_id, financial_year
From Table
Group By company_id, financial_year
Having Count(Person_Id) > 1
```

and for (2):  (when (1) is false, which person_id's and company_id's and financial_year's co-occur more than once

```
Select person_id, company_id, financial_year
From Table T
Where Not Exists 
     (Select * From Table
      Where company_id = T.company_id 
         And financial_year = T.financial_year          
      Having Count(Person_Id) > 1)
Group By person_id, company_id, financial_year
Having Count(*) > 1
```

Comment: (a) The table was (unusually - but the questioner is to be complimented for doing so) given the name of Role.  (b) Queries 1 and 2 look good.  Your third query is not what I'd expect, and hence leads to query 4 not being what I'd expect either.

Comment: yes, in re-reading, I don't see the distinction between the query listed as (1), and just the count of distinct instances of the entire triplet...